# What statistical test to use when two groups may be related?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, repeated-measures

For instance, The two groups are like the following:

* T-2 means the 2nd record of patient 'T'. The orders don't matter.

```
Group A (N=40000 or 1000):
A-1
A-2
A-3
A-4
B-1
B-2
C-1

Group B (N=2000):
A-5
A-6
B-3
```

Any records of patient C may not exist in Group B.

I want to confirm that whether there is significant difference between group A and B.

I tried to use t-test or Mann-Whitney tests but it needs independence of the groups or that the two groups must be paired.

In this situation, what statistical test can I use?

Comment: Look into repeated measures, peruse the tag [tag:repeated-measures]. Maybe add it. While at it, also tell us more about the context, the sample size, ...